# How to preload variables in a component style

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I successfully configure webpack for loading scss style that is in my components. 
I use a `<style lang="scss"></style>` and it goes well.
I used the `vue-cli` with the webpack installation.
But I would need to call some of my scss variables from there, so I guess I would need a kind of preload?

Is there a way to do it without having to `@import` in each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `sass-resources-loader`.
The solution is provided in vue-loader's [official document](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html). Please check the section named `Loading a global settings file`.

PS: Actually, it's been discussed as an issue for quite a while. You can check the discussion [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328).