# File to import not found

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm trying to import my SCSS file with all vars and mixins definitions to all components I have. File name for defs is _defs.scss:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "styles/defs";

some component styling
</style>
```

I also used alias in webpack to define where to look for styles folder:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
    styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles/")
  }
}
```

But for some reason webpack still throws error telling he can't find the import file.
Where am I wrong?

[image: Project Structure]

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWrxd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preload variables in a component style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544300/how-to-preload-variables-in-a-component-style)

Comment: Question is not about ways of defining vars in global scope. Question is about why my paths are not working.

Comment: Hi, you mean you already imported `sass-resources-loader`?

Comment: Hello, I mean I don't use it in here. I ask why can't webpack find imported file, however I defined where to look for it in resolve.alias.

Comment: Okay, would you please share your project's structure?

Comment: Sure. Added project structure picture.

Comment: Would you please check if prepending `~` could work or not? See: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports

Comment: Oh my, thank you, my friend! It actually worked. This thing took solid part of my time.

Comment: Great! How about adding an answer here so it will help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
@import "styles/defs";
```

to

```
@import "~styles/defs";
```

will solve the problem. See: [explanation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use webpack in months, but can you check this:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html,
http://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but it seems that everything is right. I've been breaking my head for some time already, so decided to write here in case I can't see some mistake I made.